# How to perform the Onclick event in primeNG menu bar

Tags: angular, primeng

How to perform the On-click event using the PrimeNG.

When we click on the New menu bar to get the UserFormComponent.html page to Add new user.Using PrimeNG how can we perform this.

My Code is available at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlf3nz
appcomponent.html

```
<p-menubar [model]="items">
```

appcomponent.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  private user = new User();  //Newly added  
  constructor(private _userService:UserService) { }  //Newly added

  title = 'clientApp';
  private items: MenuItem[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
    {
      label: 'Quotes',
      items: [
        { label: 'New ', icon: 'fa fa-refresh',  command: () => this.addNewUser()},
        { label: 'Show All', icon: 'fa fa-repeat', url: '#' }             
      ]
    }

   addNewUser(){
      this.user=this._userService.getter();
   }
```

}

this is my UserFormComponent.html

```
<div class="container">
  <form (ngSubmit)="processForm()">      
      <div class="form group">
        <label for="username">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.username">
      </div>
      <div class="form group">
          <label for="type">Type</label>
          <input type="text" name="type" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.type">
      </div>

      <div class="form group">
        <label for="modelname">Model Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="modelname" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.modelname">
      </div> 
            <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-success">
  </form>
</div>
```

this is my UserFormComponent.ts

```
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {
  private user:User;
  constructor(private _userService:UserService,private _router:Router) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.user=this._userService.getter();
  }

  processForm(){
    if(this.user.id==undefined){
       this._userService.createUser(this.user).subscribe((user)=>{
         console.log(user);
         this._router.navigate(['/']);
       },(error)=>{
         console.log(error);
       });
    }else{
       this._userService.updateUser(this.user).subscribe((user)=>{
         console.log(user);
         this._router.navigate(['/']);
       },(error)=>{
         console.log(error);
       });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use `command` to call function.

### ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
    {
      label: 'Quotes',
      items: [
        { label: 'New ', 
           icon: 'fa fa-refresh', 
           command: () => addNewUser(),
           //routerLink:"/demo"  <-- this can be moved inside the addNewUser function.
        },
        { label: 'Show All', icon: 'fa fa-repeat', url: '#' }             
      ]
    }

//Add new user
addNewUser(){
   this.user=this._userService.getter();
   this.user = new User()
}
```

Comment: i have this method in my userService.ts file which is used to create new user.

createUser(user:User){

    return this._http.post(this.baseUrl+'/car',JSON.stringify(user),  this.options).map((response:Response)=>response.json())
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
 }

but the create user template is in userFormComponent.html.

Comment: see i have edited my post to your answer. But getting the error:                                                          Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:10922)

Comment: No errors, but click event is not happening!! After clicking nothing is displaying.

Comment: Add,Delete is working Fine. But After these changes ,Now the data is not Loading in the form when i click on Edit button to Update the data. without all these changes the edit was working.

Comment: Only Empty form is appearing if i fill the details and click on save i'm able to add new data but existing i'm not able to edit and update it.

Comment: In My back end code like this: @PutMapping("/car")
 public Car updateUser(@RequestBody Car car) {
  return carRepository.save(car);
 }  and ID is @GeneratedValue.

Comment: {
       this._userService.updateUser(this.user).subscribe((user)=>{
         console.log(user);
         this._router.navigate(['/']);
       },(error)=>{
         console.log(error);
       });
    }

Comment: Yeah but i was taking the values from my springboot code in stackblitz values are not displayed.

Comment: my old code is only working for loading the data with edit button and i'm able to update the data!!! but when i click on AddNew vehicle option in the menu to add new data i'm getting the form with loaded value of last edited. Not getting the empty form to add new data. if i haven't clicked on edit button and if i click on  AddNew vehicle option in the menu to add new data i'm getting the empty form to add new data. My code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlf3nz

Comment: User list is nit coming in your demo. Add some sample data.

Comment: i have added the sample data to display in the data grid please do check at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlf3nz